# Django ListData on DetailView from Array

Tags: python, django

here my `models.py`

```
class Absent(models.Model):
    ...
    ListOfDate = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='Nothing')
    ...
```

in my case `ListOfDate` data will look like this:

```
[datetime.date(2018, 4, 18), 
 datetime.date(2018, 5, 15), 
 datetime.date(2018, 5, 16), 
 datetime.date(2018, 5, 17)]
```

I use `ListOfDate.append(value)` to fill `ListOfData`.

here my `views.py`

```
class Attend(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'attends'
    model = models.Attend
```

on `ListView` commonly use

```
  {% for attend in attends %}
    <td>{{ attends.ListOfDate }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
```

for showing list of data. but it will be all in one column. like this:

```
[datetime.date(2018, 4, 18), 
 datetime.date(2018, 5, 15), 
 datetime.date(2018, 5, 16), 
 datetime.date(2018, 5, 17)]
```

in my case I want to list `ListOfDate` like above but not in one column. Like this:

```
+-----+--------------------------------+
| #   | Date                           |
+-----+--------------------------------+
| 1   | [datetime.date(2018, 4, 18),   |  
|     |  datetime.date(2018, 5, 15),   |
|     |  datetime.date(2018, 5, 16),   |
|     |  datetime.date(2018, 5, 17)]   |
+-----+--------------------------------+

           |
           |
           v

+-----+----------------+
| #   | Date           |
+-----+----------------+
| 1   | 2018-4-18      |
+-----+----------------+
| 2   | 2018-5-15      |
+-----+----------------+
| 3   | 2018-5-16      |
+-----+----------------+
| 4   | 2018-5-17      |
+-----+----------------+
```

Comment: Then you should not store it in a `TextField`, but in a separate model with a `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextField`s, `CharField`s, are typically only used to store, *well* text. Yes there are some special subclasses to store for example JSON objects and IP addresses, but typically this is only a good idea if you do not have to *filter* on the subparts of these objects, or do not have to treat these as individual subelements. JSON fields are not bad, especially since they introduce a certain dynamic that is hard to represent in a (relational) database, but one should use them with care in a *relational* database.

Here you basically have two entities: `Absent` and an `AbsentDate`, and ther is a *one-to-many* relation between an `Absent` and `AbsentDate`. We can model this with a `ForeignKey`:

```
class Absent(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class AbsentDate(models.Model):
    absent = models.ForeignKey(Absent)
    date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date']
```

So that means we have constructed something that looks like:

```
+--------+ 1   N +------------+
| Absent |-------| AbsentDate |
+--------+       +------------+
                 | date       |
                 +------------+
```

We can then for a certain `Absent` instance, query the set of related `AbsentDate`s with:

```
our_absent_instance.absentdate_set.all()
```

So we can use this in a template like:

```
{% for attend in attends %}
  <td>
  {% for attenddate in attend.absentdate_set.all %}
      {{ attends.attenddate.date }}
  {% endfor %}
  </td>
{% endfor %}
```